# QString format %1 but multiple arguments

Tags: c++, qt

I stumbled upon this line of code in a project I am working on:

```
QString("%1").arg(2176782335, 6, 36, QChar('0')).toLatin1()
```

Why are there even multiple arguments for just `%1`? Shouldn't this only accept the first parameter in `arg()`?

Comment: Perhaps [a `QString` reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html) might be helpful. There are plenty of `arg` function overloads, all of them taking multiple arguments

Comment: sing arg() is a single argument

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [this overload](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#arg-5) of `QString::arg`. Arguments are:

- number to be displayed (integer in this case)
- minimum amount of space for the rendered number
- base (hex/dec/oct/whatever) - in your example it is quite unusual system with base 36 which uses all digits and all letters of Latin alphabet
- filler character

If you want multiple placeholders in your string, just call `arg` multiple times, like shown in the docs.

Also read about [number formats](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#number-formats).